# Python dictionary changes when using intermediate variable

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm feeding a function a string, which reads the string char by char. Based on the char being worked on, a JSON template is called from a dictionary, edited slightly and saved to a final dictionary, which will be parsed to JSON and saved.

The problem is that this template dictionary should stay constant, but it doesn't. Somehow, the values I write to the intermediate variable gets saved to the original template dictionary, messing up the subsequent data I'm trying to save.

Am I missing some basic concept of the dictionary? This is my first time working with dictionaries to such an extent so I wouldn't even be surprised.

The template dictionary:

```
self.map_legend = {"#": {"Id": 100, "Alive": False, "X": 0, "Y": 0, "Width": 1, "Height": 1, "Type": "Wall", "PlayerNumber": 0},
              "-": {"Id": 200, "Alive": False, "X": 0, "Y": 0, "Width": 1, "Height": 1, "Type": "Shield", "PlayerNumber": 0},
              "x": {"Id": 300, "Alive": False, "X": 0, "Y": 0, "Width": 1, "Height": 1, "Type": "Alien", "PlayerNumber": 0},
              "|": {"Id": 400, "Alive": False, "X": 0, "Y": 0, "Width": 1, "Height": 1, "Type": "AlienBullet", "PlayerNumber": 0},
              "!": {"Id": 500, "Alive": False, "X": 0, "Y": 0, "Width": 1, "Height": 1, "Type": "Missile", "PlayerNumber": 0},
              "i": {"Id": 500, "Alive": False, "X": 0, "Y": 0, "Width": 1, "Height": 1, "Type": "Missile", "PlayerNumber": 1},
              "M": {"Id": 600, "Alive": False, "X": 0, "Y": 0, "Width": 3, "Height": 1, "Type": "MissileController", "PlayerNumber": 0},
              "X": {"Id": 700, "Alive": False, "X": 0, "Y": 0, "Width": 3, "Height": 1, "Type": "AlienFactory", "PlayerNumber": 0},
              "A": {"Id": 800, "Alive": False, "X": 0, "Y": 0, "Width": 3, "Height": 1, "Type": "Ship", "PlayerNumber": 0},
              "V": {"Id": 800, "Alive": False, "X": 0, "Y": 0, "Width": 3, "Height": 1, "Type": "Ship", "PlayerNumber": 1},
              " ": {"Id": 900, "Alive": False, "X": 0, "Y": 0, "Width": 1, "Height": 1, "Type": "Space", "PlayerNumber": 0}}
```

The problem code:

```
for char in self.initial_game_map:
    if char != "\n":
        element = self.map_legend[char]
        self.id_counters[char] += 1

        element["Id"] = self.id_counters[char] + element["Id"]
        element["Alive"] = True
        element["X"] = char_counter % self.state_json["Map"]["Height"]
        element["Y"] = char_counter / self.state_json["Map"]["Height"]
        print self.map_legend[char]
        print element

        row.append(element)
        element = {}
        char_counter += 1

    else:
        self.state_json["Map"]["Rows"].append(row)
        row = []
```

Some output:

```
V
{'Width': 3, 'PlayerNumber': 1, 'Y': 1, 'X': 2, 'Type': 'Ship', 'Id': 801, 'Alive': True, 'Height': 1}
{'Width': 3, 'PlayerNumber': 1, 'Y': 1, 'X': 2, 'Type': 'Ship', 'Id': 801, 'Alive': True, 'Height': 1}
#
{'Width': 1, 'PlayerNumber': 0, 'Y': 0, 'X': 18, 'Type': 'Wall', 'Id': 103, 'Alive': True, 'Height': 1}
{'Width': 1, 'PlayerNumber': 0, 'Y': 0, 'X': 18, 'Type': 'Wall', 'Id': 103, 'Alive': True, 'Height': 1}
```

the `element` variable is behaving as its supposed to, but you can see that `self.map_legend` assumes the value of `element` for some reason after `element` is changed, which is NOT what I want. What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`element` and `self.map_legend[char]` point to the same dictionary and thus if you update `element` you will update the values of  the dictionary `self.map_legend[char]`. You seem to want a copy so use:

```
element = self.map_legend[char].copy()
```

Reference in the python documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html. As the dictionaries are shallow you don't need `.deepcopy()`

Comment: Thanks, it works. I suspected it might be something like this, but wasn't sure.

Comment: @Jaycee After 17 years of Python programming, it still sometimes bites me. BTW the same caution should be taken when using lists. In that case use `newlist = oldlist[:]` (as long as the list is shallow).

Comment: Thanks for the tip :) what exactly makes a list/dictionary 'deep'?

Comment: @Jaycee (there is probably an official definition), but the rule of thumb is: it is deep if any of the values (in the dict, or list) would require a (shallow) copy itself (i.e. such a value is a list, a dict, an instance of a class)

Answer (score -1):

You need to [deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) the dictionary, else the original will get modified.

```
from copy import deepcopy

element = deepcopy(self.map_legend[char])
```